# Why can't GDB find some functions to disassemble by name?

Tags: c++, gdb, name-mangling

Sometimes there is a function in my binary that I'm sure hasn't been optimized away, because it's called by another function:

```
(gdb) disassemble 'k3::(anonymous namespace)::BM_AwaitLongReadyChain(testing::benchmark::State&)'
Dump of assembler code for function k3::(anonymous namespace)::BM_AwaitLongReadyChain(testing::benchmark::State&):
   [...]
   0x00000000003a416d <+45>:    call   0x3ad0e0 <k3::(anonymous namespace)::RecursivelyAwait<k3::(anonymous namespace)::Immediate17>(unsigned long, k3::(anonymous namespace)::Immediate17&&)>
End of assembler dump.
```

But if I ask GDB to disassemble it using the very same name that it refers to the function with, it claims the function doesn't exist:

```
(gdb) disassemble 'k3::(anonymous namespace)::RecursivelyAwait<k3::(anonymous namespace)::Immediate17>(unsigned long, k3::(anonymous namespace)::Immediate17&&)'
No symbol "k3::(anonymous namespace)::RecursivelyAwait<k3::(anonymous namespace)::Immediate17>(unsigned long, k3::(anonymous namespace)::Immediate17&&)" in current context.
```

However, if I disassemble it using its address, it works fine:

```
(gdb) disassemble 0x3ad0e0
Dump of assembler code for function k3::(anonymous namespace)::RecursivelyAwait<k3::(anonymous namespace)::Immediate17>(unsigned long, k3::(anonymous namespace)::Immediate17&&):
   0x00000000003ad0e0 <+0>:     push   rbp
  [...]
End of assembler dump.
```

This is terribly inconvenient, because I don't know the address a priori—I have to go disassemble a caller just to find the address of the callee. It's really cumbersome.

**How can I get GDB to disassemble this function by name?** I assume this is some issue with name mangling/canonicalization, probably around the rvalue references and/or anonymous namespaces, but I can't figure out what exactly is going on. I'm using GDB `10.0-gg5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I ask GDB to disassemble it using the very same name that it refers to the function with, it claims the function doesn't exist

1. There are many possible mangling schemes; the relationship between mangled and unmangled names is not `1:1`.
2. The parser built into GCC which turns `foo::bar(int)` into something which can be used to lookup the symbol in the symbol table may have bugs.

> This is terribly inconvenient, because I don't know the address a priori—I have to go disassemble a caller just to find the address of the callee.

If the called function is already on the stack (i.e. part of active call chain), you can easily disassemble it via `disas $any_address_in_fn` -- you don't need to give GDB the starting address. So you could do e.g. `frame 5` followed by `disas $pc` -- GDB will find enclosing function in the symbol table and disassemble it in its entirety.

Another option is to get the address from file:line info: `info line foo.cc:123` followed by `disas $addr_given_by_previous_command`.

If you know that `foo::bar()` exists somewhere, but don't know its source location, another option is to set a breakpoint on it via e.g. `rbreak 'foo::bar'`. This will tell you the address where the breakpoint was set, and you can `disassemble` that address.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that I'm using GDB as a glorified disassembler; I'm disassembling without running the binary, so using `frame` doesn't help. `info line` is helpful though, thanks. I get that mangling skew would cause this, but that should probably seen as a bug too, right? In general I feel like if GDB gives me a name in its output that should be a name that is accepted by its input.